# Heroku: Does preboot work if I only have one dyno?

Tags: heroku

I currently have one hobby dyno and I'd like to upgrade it to Standard 1x because of the preboot feature laid out here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preboot

> Instead of stopping the existing set of web dynos before starting the
>   new ones, preboot ensures that the new web dynos are started (and
>   receive traffic) before the existing ones are terminated. This can
>   contribute to zero downtime deployments.

The wording is confusing because it sounds like I must have more than 1 dyno for it to work. An old one and a new one. Is this true? Or can I do zero downtime deploys with just 1 standard dyno?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also works with 1 dyno, since the second dyno then is handled by heroku in the background. We're heavily using it for all kinds of applications.

The article already states most of the important details.